# $\log(1+i)=\frac 12\log2+i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi)$, where's the$ 1/2$ from?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I got $\log(z)=\log |z| + i \arg(z)$

$\Rightarrow \log(1+i)= \log(1+1) + i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi) =\log 2 + i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi)$ instead. 
I couldn't figure out where the $\frac 12$ is from..??

Also, what's the difference between Log and log??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value is the square root of the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts. So here, $|1+i| = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt 2$.

And $\log (\sqrt 2) = \log (2^{\frac 12}) = \frac 12 \log 2$, by the rules of logs.

As for the difference between "log" and "Log", the latter generally refers to the principal value of the multi-valued complex logarithm. For more detail, please see the wikipedia page on Complex logarithm here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value